# Convert String or NSUrl in order to use in UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am a bit lost with optionals, AnyObjects and Strings. I have an application where I simply want to open the ActivityController when a button is pressed. Given a URL, several options to share the URL should come up then.
I couldn't find a way yet in which it works, either Xcode says it can't convert to AnyObject, or I'm getting nil.

What is the proper way of doing this?
What I have so far:

```
let data = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject] //Getting a snapshot from Firebase

let dataurl = data["url"] as! String //Prefix is url, this gives just the URL
let dataurlstring = NSURL(string: dataurl!)

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: dataurlstring, applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: Can you paste an example of snap.value?

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa `print(data) = ["url": https://www.youtube.com/]`, and `print(dataurl) = Optional("https://www.youtube.com/")`

Comment: I added a "answer", let me know if it works, otherwise let me know the errors please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and let me know if it works for you? It's not a proper answer but just a starting point to fix it:

```
func showAlert(with snapValues: [String: AnyObject]?) {
    guard let snapValues = snapValues, let dataurl = snapValues["url"] as? String, let dataurlstring = NSURL(string: dataurl) else {
        return
    }

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [dataurlstring], applicationActivities: nil)
    //Continue to show the alert or return the object activityVC 
}
```

and the call it like this:

```
let snapValues = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject]
showAlert(with: snapValues)
```

*if you want to avoid the optional parameter in the function change the code like this:*

1. Function:

   ```
   func showAlert(with snapValues: [String: AnyObject]) {
       guard let dataurl = snapValues["url"] as? String, let dataurlstring = NSURL(string: dataurl) else {
               return
       }
       ....
   }
   ```
2. Call:

   ```
   if let snapValues = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
       showAlert(with: snapValues)
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm getting the error that `dataurlstring` being a NSURL can't be converted to the expected `[AnyObject]` in the last line.

Comment: Thanks, but now when I'm trying to call it, I'm getting that snap.value being 'AnyObject?' can't be converted to expected '[String: AnyObject]?'

Comment: @Warhost this seems another problem which is not about your question.

Comment: No worries, if my answer helped you then mark it as right, I would appreciate it